# stop audio help using swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

When I make a button to stop audio and tap it once, it stops the audio. When I tap it again, it resumes the audio from the point at which it left off at. 
This is the code from that part, it is also in the code below,

```
}
// This Action allows users to stop the audio
@IBAction func stop(_ sender: UIButton) {
if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
    audioPlayer.stop()
} else {
    self.audioPlayer.play()
}
```

What I want the audio to do is to be able to stop when I push the button so that no matter how many times I push the button to stop the audio, it will not resume the audio at all. but then if I push the buttons to play sounds then they will play the sounds again.

Here is my code,

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  app21
//
//  Created by Jared Evan Miller on 8/14/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Jared Evan Miller. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let soundFilenames = ["5","8","7","4","6","1","3","2","9"]
var audioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer]()
var lastAudioPlayer = 0
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var audioPlayer1 = AVAudioPlayer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

// set up audio players
   for sound in soundFilenames{
        do {
            // Try to do somerhing
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: "wav")!);
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)

            audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
        }
        catch {

            // Catch the error that is thrown
            audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())


        }
               }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Get the audioPlayer that corresponds to the button that they tapped
    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer.play()
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer.play()
}
// This Action allows users to stop the audio
@IBAction func stop(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    } else {
        self.audioPlayer.play()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below :

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let soundFilenames = ["5","8","7","4","6","1","3","2","9"]
var audioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer]()
var lastAudioPlayer = 0
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var audioPlayer1 = AVAudioPlayer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // set up audio players
   for sound in soundFilenames{
       do {
            // Try to do somerhing
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: "wav")!);
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)

            audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
        }
        catch {
            // Catch the error that is thrown
            audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Get the audioPlayer that corresponds to the button that they tapped
    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer.play()
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer.play()
}
// This Action allows users to stop the audio
@IBAction func stop(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I have a problem that I want to make a button that plays a sound and then will show a view controller that I want

Comment: What is your messenger name

Comment: You help me so well

Comment: I am asking Vinci app

Comment: I meant vini app